# マルチポスト先で問題が解決しているが、SOjaでの質問が放置されたままの投稿をどう扱う？

Tags: 討議, マルチポスト

類似の質問サイトにもマルチポストされている質問が、他のサイトではどうやら解決しているように見える一方で、残念ながらスタック・オーバーフローでの質問が放置されているケースがいくつかあります。

直近の投稿であれば質問者にコメントでなんらかのアクションを求めることもできますが、しばらく時間の経っている投稿だとこれらも難しいように思います。

誰かが代わりにコミュニティwikiとして投稿することも考えられますが、(出典を明記したとしても) 他サイトからの単なるコピーを投稿するのはマナー/モラルの面で個人的にやや気が引けます。

web検索して日本語で回答が出てくるようにするのがこのサイトでの目標である一方、他サイトで回答が出ているならそちらに譲るのも一つの方法なんじゃないかと思います。

今回のようなケースであれば、該当質問を削除するのも選択肢の一つかと思いますがいかがでしょうか？
(もちろんコピペではなく別の回答を投稿出来る人がいるのであればそちらでも構いません)

Comment: 質問者はもはや興味がなく、しかし解決していないため[コミュニティボット](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%e3%82%b3%e3%83%9f%e3%83%a5%e3%83%8b%e3%83%86%e3%82%a3)により何度も何度もトップに引き戻されてくる、というのはとても不毛なので、何かしら結論づけて欲しいものです。

Answer (score 8):

解決している先が他の質問サイトであろうと「他のサイトに詳細な解決法が載っている」というケースとしてまとめられると考えています。つまり、自分の言葉で要約を書きつつ、詳細が載っているページとしてその質問ページへリンクするので良いと思っています。解決法を見つけてくるのはひとつの貢献な訳なので、コミュニティ wiki である必要もないでしょう。

質問を手動で削除するのは、将来的に他の回答があつまる可能性を除去してしまうので最終手段としたいです。

Answer (score 3):

@nekketsuuu さんの説明はある程度理解できる部分はあるものの、著作権やその質問での前提知識が必要になる、などの問題もあり、特に、マルチポストされながら放置される質問は、 ja.stackoverflow.com にて回答を付与するのが難しいと思われる場合があると思っています。

質問の削除を行う場合、その質問は削除に先立ってクローズされている必要があると思っています。であるならば、むしろまず議論されるべきは、「マルチポスト先で解決していて、かつ、 jaso としては回答が付与される・できる見込がない質問である」という理由で質問をクローズするのは妥当か、という話になるかな、と思っています。

そして、それはそうとクローズや削除をする前に、スタック・オーバーフローの質問は、常に投票(upvote/downvote)が可能です。個人的には、スタック・オーバーフローの投稿(質問・回答)に対する投票は、「この投稿がこのサイトに存在することはプラスである・マイナスである」を表す意思表示のための行動だ、と最近は思っています。であるならば、削除妥当な質問がもし仮にあるとしたら、それはマイナス投票妥当たりうる質問だろうな、とは思っており、なので、ひとまずクローズ・削除の議論・意思決定がなされる前であっても、各個人がマイナス投票でそれを表すことは、個人的には妥当なのではないか、と思っています。

Comment: マルチポストしているというだけで「はなはだしくずさんな、まったく努力していない投稿」とするのはちょっと私の感性とは離れるなあ、と思っています。　https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: 「はなはだしくずさんな、まったく努力していない投稿、または明らかに、そして危険なほど不正確な回答」というのは、「コミュニティにとって質問および回答が役に立たない」ことに対する十分条件かなぁ、という個人的な感覚、ではあります。

Comment: マルチポストしたことで自己解決しているのに放置されているという問題が顕在化しただけで、実際はマルチポストが発見できてないケースやオフラインで解決してそのままというのもきっとあると思います